# Stratified sampling with unknown strata sizes

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, stratification

I'm in a setting where I have natural population strata (that I can infer from the samples), but I don't know the strata sizes. Are there ways to get valid confidence intervals in this setting?

Comment: Well, yes there are. Tell us more.

Comment: What more information would you want @Carl? If you have reference I'd be happy to go through those myself!

Comment: One way to narrow the flow of information requested to something tractable would be to show some data, and failing that to characterize the variable types and behaviors enough to elicit a succinct response.